# Using ServiceStack Funq Dependency Injection in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, servicestack

In ServicePlugin.cs, I have defined this in the `Register()` method:

```
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<ApplicationUserProfileRepository, 
    IApplicationUserRepository>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

I then, have a ServiceStack service which attempts to resolve it as a normal dependency:

```
public class UserService : ServiceStack.Service
{

    private readonly IApplicationUserRepository _repository;

    public UserService(IApplicationUserRepository rep)
    {
        _repository = rep;
    }
```

Finally, in my MVC controller, I am attempting to call the service like so:

```
using (UserService action = new UserService(new ApplicationUserProfileRepository()))
{
    // etc...
```

The code above works fine; but instead, I want to have the dependency injected automatically so that I can simply do this:

```
using (UserService action = new UserService())
{
    // etc...
```

Is this not how dependency injection is supposed to be done with Service Stack and MVC?

**Note:**  I got the example from here https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simplifying injection:

If you make the repository a `public` property on the `UserService` then Funq will inject the dependancy automatically when you resolve the Service, given that you have registered it with the container, so you don't have to add it via the constructor. Though your method of constructor injection will still work, given you follow the resolve instructions below.

Make the repository `public`:

```cs
public class UserService : ServiceStack.Service
{
    public IApplicationUserRepository Repository { get; set; }
}
```

Register the repository instance with the container:

```cs
HostContext.Container.Register<IApplicationUserRepository>(c => new ApplicationUserProfileRepository()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

## Get instance by resolving from the Funq Container:

Then when you want to use the `UserService` resolve it rather than creating the instance directly, it's this action which will ensure the dependancies are injected:

```cs
using(var userService = HostContext.ResolveService<UserService>())
{
    // Dependancy is already wired up
    userService.Repository ...
}
```

Comment: One small note that might be worth mentioning:  The line `container.RegisterAutoWired<IApplicationUserRepo...` gives an error that reads, "No method RegisterAutoWired takes 1 arguments."  My old `container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<ApplicationUserProfileRepo...` still seems to work, however.

Comment: @user1477388 Good catch. It should just be `Register<T>`. I have updated. You're registration method will work equally as well too.